# pycharm + flask surprising working directory

Tags: flask, pycharm

(Modified to answer the questions in the first comment.)

I am using Flask in PyCharm and getting different results than when I run it from the terminal. In particular, the working directory of the Python program is different under Pycharm. So this code works correctly when running flask from the command line and the print os.getcwd() displays '/Users/Wes/Dropbox/Programming/Python/etpruncnt2'.

However if I run the same code in Pycharm the os.getcwd() displays '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/bin' and the file open fails 
with IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/results.json'.

The root of the project in PyCharm is /Users/Wes/Dropbox/Programming/Python/etpruncnt2. I have also added a screenshot of the project structure in the PyCharm GUI.

[image: Project pane]

I suppose I must have the configuration wrong in PyCharm. I have included a screenshot.

[image: configuration screen]

What should I do?

```
@app.route('/running_count')
def running_count():
    print os.getcwd()
    with open('data/results.json', 'r') as resultFile:
        resultData = json.load(resultFile)
    return str(resultData)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Only Have Shown Script Path

How is project structure ? When you are creating new project you are telling pycharm the project root and may you mixed that part :)

Comment: I have edited the question to answer the question here. PyCharm shows the route to the project and its directory structure correctly. I can't see anything in the setup that would make PyCharm think the project is rooted in the middle of the Mac Application directory.

Comment: On the 2nd screenshot you have not specified "Working Directory" :) which must be the root of your project.

Comment: My Solution Worked ?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to close this. The immediate problem is that the Working Directory in the config was not filled in.

Most default setups for PyCharm do fill that in, but the setup for flask does not.

I have filed a low-urgency bug report with IntelliJ.